# Objects in Illustrator Not Aligning to Pixel Grid Correctly

Tags: adobe-illustrator, alignment, pixel

[image: What my Illustration looks like]

I'm having problems aligning my objects to the pixel grid in Illustrator. As you can see in the picture, my object is correctly aligned with the pixel grid. However there are still parts outside of the green transform lines. Does anyone know how I can fix this? I've been trying align correctly with the direct select tool for over an hour with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Are these objects created in Ill. or imported? make sure stroke is off, and try to create new objects with Align to pixel Grid checked in the Transform Panel.